# Count decimal places - Money column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I identify the number of decimal places from a money column in SQL Server?

For example: If I have 2 registers. Each one with those values:

- Amount = 150.13
- Amount = 250.1463

There is any query to differ between these two registers? Showing just the number of decimal places in each register?

Sample Query:

```
    CREATE TABLE #tbl_temp (
    Amount MONEY
);

INSERT INTO #tbl_temp VALUES (150.13); -- Sample with 2 decimal places
INSERT INTO #tbl_temp VALUES (250.1463); -- Sample with 4 decimal places


-- First Try
SELECT Amount,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(VARCHAR, Amount)) > 0
        THEN LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROUND(Amount, 10))) - CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROUND(Amount, 10))) -1
        ELSE 0
    END AS DecimalPlaces 
  FROM #tbl_temp;

-- Second Try
  SELECT Amount,
     CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(VARCHAR, Amount)) > 0 
        THEN LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Amount)) - CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(VARCHAR, Amount))
        ELSE 0 
    END AS decimal_places
 FROM #tbl_temp;
```

The two tries above were not successful...
I expected the number 2 and the number 4 in each query, in column **decimal_places**
It’s possible to do this? Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/7Wk-pk_n

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Once you store that value as `MONEY`, you don't know any longer, which precision the original number had. `150.13` and `150.1300` will be shown as the same value. So, not knowing the sigificant decimals any longer, what do you gain from knowing that the last digit that is not a zero happens to be in the first, second, third or fourth place behind the decimal separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be

```
SELECT *,
       CASE 0
         WHEN Amount % 1 THEN 0
         WHEN Amount % 0.1 THEN 1
         WHEN Amount % 0.01 THEN 2
         WHEN Amount % 0.001 THEN 3
         WHEN Amount % 0.0001 THEN 4
       END
FROM   #tbl_temp
```

Or a slightly more concise way of doing the same approach

```
SELECT *, 
        (SELECT MIN(Num) FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4)) V(Num) WHERE Amount % POWER($0.1, Num) = 0) 
FROM #tbl_temp
```

But if I pay exactly £1.00 this is accurate to two decimal places despite the last two being zeroes so be careful with how you use the results.

Comment: While I don't really prefer any of the solutions over the others, this answer gets my upvote because of the warning at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting to varchar without the trailing zeroes as @Jonas Metzler uses, and then find the decimal point position by splitting the result in characters. Then you subtract the length from the decimal point position in the string.

```
;with numbers as (
        select top 20 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id) n
        from sys.objects 
)
select *, len (sAmount) AmountLength, n DecimalPointPosition, len (sAmount) - n DigitalPlaces
from #tbl_temp
cross apply (select convert(varchar(20), convert(float, Amount ), 128) sAmount) ca
cross apply (select substring(sAmount, n, 1) chr, n from numbers ) ca2
where chr= '.'
```

you can try it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/uv17pqdq (see first and last column)

Comment: I wrote my idea as comment rather than as answer because I think there must be a better, simple way and dislike my strange way ;) This here seems still too complex. But to be honest, I couldn't find a nice, short query yet. Maybe it's not possible because SQL Server is not good in such things?

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you, I don't like my method either, I just showed another way to solve it with a table approach mode.

Comment: Seems like a long way to go

Answer (score 0):

I know others have already answered, but since I already worked on it I'm posting my answer below...

```
select case when round(Amount,0)-Amount  = 0 then 0
            when round(Amount,1)-Amount  = 0 then 1
            when round(Amount,2)-Amount  = 0 then 2
            when round(Amount,3)-Amount  = 0 then 3
            else 4 end 
from #tbl_temp
```